# Angular show div on hover using ElementRef Query List

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `ngFor` on my project and I want to show a div on mouse hover, for this I'm using `@Input` notation.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="col s12 m6" style="position: relative" *ngFor="let res of hostInfo.residents; let i = index">
   <div class="kids-container" (mouseenter)="showDeleteAction(i)" (mouseleave)="showDeleteAction(i)">
      <span>{{ res.firstName }} {{ res.lastName }}
         <br>
         <span>{{ res.relationship }}</span>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="actions" #deleteAction>
   <a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red">
      <i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
</div>
```

And my ts

```
@ViewChildren('deleteAction', { read: ElementRef}) deleteAction: QueryList<ElementRef>;

showDeleteAction(i) {
   const nativeElement = this.deleteAction.toArray();
   const actionDiv = nativeElement[i].nativeElement;
   return actionDiv.style.display = actionDiv.style.display === 'block' ;
}
```

It doesn't work at all. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong here? Is showDeleteActions being fired at all? if you put a console.log() in there does it get shown in the console?

Comment: Yes! It's been fired but it's not showing the div. It's like if the style wasn't being applied. It console.log the div and its child: `<div _ngcontent-c3="" class="actions"><a _ngcontent-c3="" class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red"><i _ngcontent-c3="" class="material-icons">delete</i></a></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You  are assigning wrong css here.

Use it as below:-

```
return actionDiv.style.display = 'block'   //it will display them
```

If you want to toggle:-

```
return actionDiv.style.display = (actionDiv.style.display === 'block') ? 'none' :'block' ;   // if not showing show and if already showing then hide it .
```